# how to add linebreak in iPhone notification alert message or plain text on SMS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

what is the code for the line break in the iPhone notification alert message or plain text on

SMS ?

Thanks

Comment: This is duplicate of a question asked 2 hours ago

Comment: actually, i nid to clafify more about this question. The Push notification will alert the user in term of text, audio and so on. what if we nid to customize the text content such add the linebreak in  order to make the content presentable?so, it is the escape sequence can be implemented ?

any pointer to this question , i will truly appreciated it...

Comment: in addition, i will implement on the UIAlertView.

Comment: did you get answer on this? \n doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed with \n

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message\nwith linebreak" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
[alertView release];
```

This shows an alert with a nice line break.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried '\n'?