# iOS APNS creating a message

Tags: html, ios, apple-push-notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to add linebreak in iPhone notification alert message or plain text on SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151933/how-to-add-linebreak-in-iphone-notification-alert-message-or-plain-text-on-sms)

Is it possible to put a `<br>` in the message sent to the APNS server/devices, so that you get a break in the message? Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: I've never worked with APNS so I'm not sure if this is true, but in Objective-C you use `\n` for line break.

Comment: That works but its giving me a space right before "Units". $message = "$call - $location - $station\n Units: $units";

Comment: Are you putting this space after \n? Because there is no need for a gap there.

Comment: Oh wait I figured it out, $units has a space at the beginning. Thanks that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C you can use `\n` to signify a line break.

E.g.

`Hello\nworld!`

will output:

Hello
World!